# Restrict other processes access to my file C#

Tags: c#

I want to know how to restrict access to file by list of processes.
I have file text.txt and I want only process in my list can read that file.

Ex: Explorer.exe can't read text.txt

Comment: There is no way to do that.  Windows doesn't have any notion of process-level file ACLs.

Comment: Can you give the reasoning behind this idea?  is this a requirement made by someone who doesn't really know how Windows works (perhaps because they come from a Linux background), or are you trying to 'hide' things because you are trying to be a hacker and write a virus or something?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question. How is this related to C#?

Comment: I just don't want anyone copy my file in my USB when it's lent.

Comment: You can't restrict access but you could encrypt it so that nobody else can read it.

Comment: But when I use that encrypted file, I have to decrypt it to disk, so it could be stolen.

Answer (score 0):

Try [FileShare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.71).aspx)

```
FileStream s2 = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
```

Release the stream before opening it with your other processes.

Comment: OP wants this for "list of processes". So you need to share access somehow (named `Mutex`?)

Answer (score -1):

On the system you want to protect, create a new user, store the files you want to protect in the Documents folder of this user.  Then, the only user (or processes) that can access those files are Admin users (or users with high enough privileges) and the user you created.